# xpath replace not working?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

With this HTML

```
<tr>
                <td class="listOddRow"><a href="/bnc/page?BPPC=BPPC17111409443230443484&amp;aliasDispatcher=bankingAccountHistory&amp;key=1027510022703&amp;cAliasDispatcher=bankingStatement&amp;kookToken=wHwy83w6cX" class="listLinks" onclick="setValidExitDocument();">Chequing</a>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="listOddRow">00-227-03</td>
                <td class="listOddRow" nowrap="">0275-1</td>
                <td class="listOddRow" align="right" nowrap="">$&nbsp;28.08</td>


            </tr>
```

Anyone knows why this works

[image]

`//td[contains(text(),"00-227-03")]/parent::tr//a`

but not this? I want to remove the dashes from the `text()` before calling `contains()`

[image]

`//td[contains(replace(text(), "-", ""),"0022703")]/parent::tr//a`

Comment: and does it work so: `//td[contains(translate(text(), "-", ""),"0022703")]/parent::tr//a` ?

Comment: @splash58 it does! thanks for the help, care to explain what translate does here? I did not know that function

Comment: @ibiza why do you need to ask that question? Don't you have access to any reference information for XPath?

Comment: @MichaelKay why do you need to make that comment? Just don't look at my question, don't you have something better to do?

Comment: I make the comment with two objectives: firstly to help you become more productive as a developer, and secondly to make StackOverflow a better place to be, where people visiting the site find a better quality of questions and answers.

Comment: @MichaelKay thanks for the good intentions but I don't need your condescending remarks for being more productive and I'm sure this question can be helpful to others as well, good bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in xpath 1.0 there is no function `replace`, but there is `translate` working in the same way - it replaces in the 1st string chars presented in the 2nd one by corresponding chars in the 3rd. So, you can use the Xpath

```
//td[contains(translate(text(), "-", ""),"0022703")]/parent::tr//a
```